# near returns all documents in a collection

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a following code which should return those lat,long in mongodb which are near the ones I mentioned. But the problem is that it returns all the lat,longs.

```
$collection->ensureIndex(array("location" => "2d"));
$a=array(24.8934,67.0281);
//print_r($a);

$distance='500';

$query = array('location' => array('$near' => array(24.8934,67.0281)));


$cursor = $collection->find($query);
try{
if ($cursor) {
   echo $arr= json_encode(iterator_to_array($cursor));
 // $j= json_decode($arr,false);
echo var_dump(json_decode($arr));
$j = json_decode($arr,false);
 $lat= $j->{'57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e'}->location[0]; 
 $lng= $j->{'57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e'}->location[1]; 
} else {
    echo "{ 'status' : 'false' }";
}
```

It returns the following:

```
object(stdClass)[7]
  public '572453d55addfab49090ea71' => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public '_id' => 
        object(stdClass)[8]
          public '$id' => string '572453d55addfab49090ea71' (length=24)
      public 'location' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => float 24.8615
          1 => float 67.0099
  public '57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e' => 
    object(stdClass)[9]
      public '_id' => 
        object(stdClass)[10]
          public '$id' => string '57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e' (length=24)
      public 'location' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => float 33.7715
          1 => float 72.7511
```

Instead it should only return first document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the sample code is not working correctly is that the $distance variable is defined, but it is not being passed to the query.

You would need to modify your code to be similar to the following example:

```
$distance=500;
$cursor = $collection->find(['location' =>
['$near'=> [ 24.8934,67.0281 ],
'$maxDistance' => $distance]]);
```

For most use cases, we recommend that you should be using the newer 2dsphere index which uses earth-like geometry and GeoJSON objects.  Please review [2dsphere index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/) for more information on this functionality.

If you use a 2dsphere index, the code would be similar to this:

```
$distance=500;
$cursor = $collection->find(['location' =>
['$near'=>
['$geometry'=>
[ 'type' => "Point",  'coordinates' => [ 24.8934,67.0281 ] ],
'$maxDistance' => $distance]]]);
```

You may also find the [spherical geometry tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/) helpful.